# How to fetch only part of document from dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

For fetching document faster I want to fetch only  a part of it, as the document size can be large. How to achieve this in dynamodb?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="tab")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Doc {

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName ="id")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    Info info;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    List<Participants> participants;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    List<Phases> phases;
}
```

This below load method will load complete document. But I don't want that. I want to load only info

```
 Transaction transaction = dynamoDBMapper.load(Doc.class, txnId);
```

How to achieve that ?

Comment: Can it be done in dynamodb? Yes. But you're asking how to do it in that particular sdk, which I don't know - have a look through that sdk's docs.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a generic DynamoDB answer - you can look up the specific syntax for your language/SDK on your own.

You said that you have a large document and want to fetch only a part of it so it will be faster. This question has two parts - first how to fetch only a part of the document, and second whether it will actually be faster.

The answer for the first part is that yes - it is indeed possible to fetch only a part of the document, by passing additional parameters to the `GetItem` (or `Query`, `Scan`, etc.) request. The older parameter is `AttributesToGet`, letting you provide a list of top-level attributes you want to fetch for the item. The newer and recommended replacement is the `ProjectionExpression` parameter -  which also allows you to retrieve parts of a nested documents (an attribute which is itself a list or a map).

However, it is less obvious whether this will be "faster". First you need to know that it will **not** be cheaper - the cost of a read request is calculated based on the size of the entire item (which the DynamoDB implementation reads from disk entirely) - not just the specific attributes you ask to retrieve. It will also not be faster for DynamoDB to read the data from the disk. One thing that can be faster is the networking part (since the response is smaller), but whether or not this translates to any appreciable fastness in your application depends on your exact setup.

Comment: That's not 100% accurate. If you need to create a Secondary Index and only require a subset of attributes for that index, you can define the Projected Attributes when creating it. This will improve performance and *can* reduce costs associated with that Index.

Comment: You're right that a secondary index is a way to achieve what he wanted. Writes and storage will be more expensive, but reads will be cheaper. So it's a tradoff. You can add this idea as an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: Yep, as my comment indicates, "If you _need_ to create a Secondary Index". In which case it can be made cheaper for reads and writes. OP never actually asks about costs, so I don't feel my comment warrants an answer. I was informing you, and others who read your answer. Besides, without careful planning Index based Projected Attributes can be a pain, as you have to recreate the index to add/remove them. So best to take the simpler approach first. As the saying goes, _Premature optimization is the root of all evil_.